# compiling a C file with gcc to get x86 assembly code

Tags: c, linux, gcc, x86

I have a C file heapsort.c which Im trying to compile on a 64 bit linux machine to output the corresponding assembly code. Im using the following command:

```
 gcc -02 -S heapsort.c
```

when I type this Im getting this error message

```
 gcc:error: unrecognized option '-02'
```

I tried googling this error but nothing helpful came up. Any suggestions on how to navigate this error and get the x86 output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest even (as every pointed out is is the letter `O` not the digit `0`)

```
   gcc -O2 -fverbose-asm -S heapsort.c
```

<sup>The `-fverbose-asm` will give you more generated comments in the assembly file `heapsort.s`</sup>

BTW, passing `-Wall` to GCC is always a good habit.

if you are really curious and want to understand a bit more the internal representations inside GCC try even

```
  gcc -fdump-tree-all -O2 -S heapsort.c
```

but be prepared to get a **lot** of files.
<sup>You'll get hundreds of them, matching `heapsort.c.*`!</sup>

If you want some crude GUI interface to query the Gimple internal representation at some arbitrary source code position, consider using [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/). MELT is mostly a high-level domain specific language (with a Lisp-like syntax, powerful pattern matching, object oriented, functional, dynamically typed, ....) to extend GCC, but you can also use its (crude) [probe](http://gcc-melt.org/index.html#probe_id) to query interactively some of the GCC internal representations.

Answer (score 7):

The flag is `-O2`, not `-02`. That's a letter `O` for "optimization", not a number `0`.  You might want to look into using a font that makes the difference more obvious.

Answer (score 1):

It should be -O2 with 'O' not "zero"

Answer (score 1):

Try `-O2` instead of `-02`.  It's a letter 'O' and shorthand for "optimization level 2".